# Training a classifier with Weka is too slow

Tags: java, weka

I'm building a classifier with `Weka` and my dataset is sparse (text data). I need to build my feature vectors on my own without using `Weka`'s utiltiy classes to convert my text document to feature vectors. The problem is that training any classifier is **very** slow, although the number of features and samples is small!

I wrote a test case with artificial sparse feature vectors samples to show you how slow it is. You can run it.

```
public static void test() throws Exception {
        System.out.println( "Started test ... " + new Date() );

        Classifier clf = new SimpleLogistic();
        int numberOfFeatures = 2000;
        int numberOfSamples = 6000;
        Random rnd = new Random(0);

        //Define dataset
        FastVector attributes = new FastVector(numberOfFeatures + 1);
        for (Integer i = 0; i < numberOfFeatures; i++) {
            attributes.addElement( new Attribute(i.toString()) );
        }

        FastVector classes = new FastVector( 2 );
        classes.addElement( "Positive" );
        classes.addElement( "Negative" );

        attributes.addElement( new Attribute( "class", classes ) );
        Instances data = new Instances("", attributes, 100);
        data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes()-1);

        //Create artifical sparse feature vectors for the positive class
        for ( int i = 0; i < numberOfSamples/2; i++ ) {
            double[] vec = new double[numberOfFeatures + 1];
            vec[rnd.nextInt(numberOfFeatures)] = 1;
            vec[rnd.nextInt(numberOfFeatures)] = 1;
            vec[rnd.nextInt(numberOfFeatures)] = 1;
            vec[rnd.nextInt(numberOfFeatures)] = 1;

            Instance instance = new Instance(1.0, vec);
            instance.setDataset(data);
            Instance sparseInstance = new SparseInstance(instance);
            sparseInstance.setDataset(data);
            sparseInstance.setClassValue("Positive");
            data.add(sparseInstance);
        }

        //Create artifical sparse feature vectors for the negative class
        for ( int i = 0; i < numberOfSamples/2; i++ ) {
            double[] vec = new double[numberOfFeatures + 1];
            vec[rnd.nextInt(numberOfFeatures)] = 1;
            vec[rnd.nextInt(numberOfFeatures)] = 1;
            vec[rnd.nextInt(numberOfFeatures)] = 1;
            vec[rnd.nextInt(numberOfFeatures)] = 1;

            Instance instance = new Instance(1.0, vec);
            instance.setDataset(data);
            Instance sparseInstance = new SparseInstance(instance);
            sparseInstance.setDataset(data);
            sparseInstance.setClassValue("Negative");
            data.add(sparseInstance);
        }
        System.out.println( "Building classifier ... " );
        clf.buildClassifier(data);
        System.out.println( new Date() );
    }
```

I'm not sure if there is something I should do to make it faster! It acutally doesn't make sense to me, because gradient descent should run very quickly. I tried a `MultilayerPerceptron` classifier with a hidden layer and a single hidden unit and 1 epoch and it was **REALLY REALLY** slow!

**Edit:**

I tried the same idea of the test case but with `scikit-learn` and it was fast like light! Here:

```
import numpy as np
import random
from sklearn import linear_model

numberOfFeatures = 2000;
numberOfSamples = 6000;

X = np.zeros( (numberOfSamples, numberOfFeatures) )
y = np.zeros(numberOfSamples)

for i in xrange( numberOfSamples ):
    X[i][ random.randint(0, numberOfFeatures - 1) ] = 1;
    X[i][ random.randint(0, numberOfFeatures - 1) ] = 1;
    X[i][ random.randint(0, numberOfFeatures - 1) ] = 1;
    X[i][ random.randint(0, numberOfFeatures - 1) ] = 1;
    X[i][ random.randint(0, numberOfFeatures - 1) ] = 1;
    X[i][ random.randint(0, numberOfFeatures - 1) ] = 1;
    X[i][ random.randint(0, numberOfFeatures - 1) ] = 1;
    X[i][ random.randint(0, numberOfFeatures - 1) ] = 1;

for i in xrange( 100 ):
    y[i] = 1


clf = linear_model.LogisticRegression()
print 'fitting'
clf.fit(X, y)

print 'done!'
```

Comment: You might consider posting over at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/